# labelling nodes in bubble chart

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 js and I was trying to create a bubble chart with the help of force simulation.
However I have created the bubbles but not able to display lables on bubbles.   Below is my code, any suggestion on this code will be a great help to me.

Thankss in advance

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var width = 1500;
var height = 1000;
var color  = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width",width)
        .attr("height",height).
        append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(0,0)");

var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0,130000]).range([10,100])

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("x",d3.forceX(width/2).strength(0.05))
        .force("y",d3.forceY(height/2).strength(0.05))
        .force("collide",d3.forceCollide(function(d){ return radiusScale(d.value)+1;}))


d3.queue().
    defer(d3.csv,"historylogs.csv").await(ready);

function ready(error,datapoints){

console.log(datapoints);

datapoints = datapoints.map(function(d){ d.value = +d["size_kw"]; return d; });

datapoints = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) { return d.install_type;})
 .rollup(function(d) { 
   return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.value; });
  }).entries(datapoints);

console.log(datapoints);

var nodes = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data(datapoints)
    .enter()
 .append("g");

var circles= nodes                                                                                   
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r",function(d){ return radiusScale(d.value);} )
        .attr("fill",function(d) { return color(d.value);})
        .attr("opacity",0.5)
        //.attr("dx", function(d){return d.key})
            //.text(function(d){return d.key})
        //.on('mouseover',function(d){})

var text=   nodes
        .append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")      
        .text(function(d){  return d.key; })
        .style({
            "fill":"black", 
            "font-family":"Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, san-serif",
            "font-size": "12px"
          });


    simulation.nodes(datapoints).on('tick',ticked);

    function ticked(){
            circles.attr("cx",function(d){ return d.x;})
                .attr("cy",function(d){ return d.y;});
            //text.attr("x",function(d){ return d.x;})
                //.attr("y",function(d){ return d.y;});
            }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

As you have created `<g>` element for grouping circle and the text elements, you can update the position of both elements by simply setting the `transform` attribute of group element. So change your tick function as shown below.

```
  function ticked() {
    nodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  }
```

Comment: it worked, could you also tell how to display data related to each node whenever we render mouse pointer over  the bubble.

Comment: Sorry Harshita. I didn't get you. You already have labels(key values) for each node. So what's the expected `data` to be displayed on mouseover? and how? as a tooltip?

Comment: Whatever the layout, you can add tooltip to d3 charts like this - http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369